# Why Selection event not triggered when selection is done using keyboard?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have this Eclipse RCP application which uses SWT. Here is a sample code.

```
    Combo combo = new Combo(shell, SWT.NONE);
    combo.setItems(items); // items is a String[]
    combo.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));

    combo.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
         
        @Override
        public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("In widgetDefaultSelected");
        }

        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("In widgetSelected");
        }
    });
```

The combo has been set up in the code for auto complete. The selection event is supposed to get triggered for mouse or keyboard events. A selection using mouse triggers the selection event but one with keyboard does not. I am trying to see why.

My eclipse is not the latest, it is version is 3.6.2 and the swt JARs that come with it. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: This code works fine on the current Eclipse 2020-09 (4.17) on macOS 10.15.7. It might be something that was fixed sometime in the 10 years and 17 releases between 3.6.2 and 4.17

Comment: @greg-449 Unfortunately, we are not in a position to upgrade.  We are also on Windows 10/Java 8 platform. Do you think this is an Eclipse bug? If so could there be work arounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the selection event is not triggered with keyboard, I added a KeyListener to the combo widget and check to see if the user has pressed enter key.

```
    combo.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.keyCode==SWT.CR || e.keyCode==SWT.KEYPAD_CR) { // Enter key
                Combo c = (Combo) e.getSource();
                System.out.println(c.getText());
                // Do rest of processing
            }
        }
    });
```

Seems like I am getting the selected item out of the list box. So far it seems to be working OK.

Answer (score 0):

Selection event is not used for keyboard events, the Javadoc of Combo#addSelectionListener is pretty clear here:

- `widgetSelected` is called when the user changes the combo's list selection.
- `widgetDefaultSelected` is typically called when ENTER is pressed the combo's text area.

Comment: The user presses ENTER only when he/she is selecting the item from the dropdown. In order for the call to widgetDefaultSelected() to happen, user will have to press ENTER a second time in the text area of the widget after she/he has selected the item.